# does parser always take in arguments as list?

Tags: python, django

Python Version: Python 3.5.1

Django Version: Django 1.10.2

I am trying to write my own django custom command and I noticed that to take in an argument, it always ends up as a list.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Notice that the arguments for integers is a list of integer.

I wanted to have an argument that takes in a relative path or absolute path to a directory written in obviously str format.

My question is:

1. is it even possible to only accept the argument as a single str object for the parser object?
2. if it's possible, what do I need to change?

My current code is

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('path', nargs='+', type=str)

    # Named (optional) arguments
    parser.add_argument(
        '--whiteware',
        action='store_true',
        dest='whiteware',
        default=True,
        help='Affects whiteware variants only',
    )

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    directory_in_str = options['path']

    print(directory_in_str)
```

Comment: what is the goal? Can you show an example of a valid input and an example of invalid input as a part of the question ? The `nargs='+'` is what is taking the input in as a string. Remove that, and you should get the arguments as a string.

Comment: @Exprator if i can downvote your comment I would. I already am creating the custom command file. I am talking specifically about the parser object within the custom command class

Comment: thanks @karthikr your comment was the right direction I needed. Thank you. Feel free to create an answer so I can mark it as right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the way you are creating the command line argument `path`.

From the documentation,

> nargs - The number of command-line arguments that should be consumed.

and `nargs='+'` implies one or more space separated arguments, which would be casted into a list by `argparse`.

Now, if you are expecting a string, you can just do:

```
parser.add_argument('path', type=str) #type is str by default, no need to specify this explicitly.
```

Note that `nargs` is extremely useful when you want to restrict the choice types, etc.

For example:

```
parser.add_argument('path', nargs='+', choices=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

This way, you can provide a bunch of options which would be available as a list for consumption.

Or even:

```
parser.add_argument('path', choices=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

If you want a single option as a string.

You can read more on [argparse options here in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)